# How to update React context on successful login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-state-management, react-context

When a user successfully logs in, I get a response of 200 from the server and then I want to update the variable in my ReactContext Provider. However, I am unable to do so as I can get the `toggleAuth` function inside render (as shown below) and cannot send to the function `handleSubmit`. The `toggleAuth` is a toggling function in AuthContext.

```
import {
    AuthContext
} from './AuthContext'
class SignIn extends React.Component {


    async handleSubmit(event) {
        // I get a 200 in status if it works
        const status = await res.status
        const json = await res.json();
        if (status === 200) {
            //I want to call toggleAuth here.    

        }
    }

    static contextType = AuthContext;

    render() {
        const {
            toggleAuth
        } = this.context
        return ( 
            <Form onSubmit = {
                this.handleSubmit} >
            <div>

            <Form.Group controlId = "formBasicUsername" >
            <Form.Label> Username </Form.Label> 
            <Form.Control required name = "username"
            type = "text"
            placeholder = "Enter username" / >
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId = "formBasicPassword" >
            <Form.Label > Password < /Form.Label> 
            <Form.Control required name = "password"
            type = "password"
            placeholder = "Enter password" / >
            </Form.Group>

            <Button variant = "warning"
            type = "submit" >
            Submit 
            </Button> 
            </div>   
            </div>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}
```

**AuthContext:**

```
import React, {
    Component,
    createContext
} from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

class AuthContextProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        isAuthenticated: false
    }
    toggleAuth = () => {
        this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated
        })
    }

    render() {
        return ( <
            AuthContext.Provider value = {
                {
                    ...this.state,
                    toggleAuth: this.toggleAuth
                }
            } > {
                this.props.children
            } </AuthContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

Comment: can you post the code of the context

Comment: Updated the code with it

Answer (score 0):

just make `handleSubmit` as arrow function so you can access `this.context`

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // I get a 200 in status if it works
    const status = await res.status
    const json = await res.json();
    if (status === 200) {
         const {toggleAuth} = this.context;
         toggleAuth();
    }
}
```